# Plotting Cumulative Frequency Graphs - Grouped Data

Tags: statistics

With grouped data with 'gaps' between the groups, different texts give different advice as to where to plot the cumulative frequency. Taking a simple example: Number of passengers 0 - 4 Frequency = 4, Number of passengers 5 - 9 Frequency 7. Some texts suggest plotting the cumulative frequency against 4, others at 4.5, others at 5 (on the Number of passengers axis).
Similar mixed advice also arises in other topics such as histograms.
Are there unambiguous rules, and does it depend on the type of data?
Many thanks.
My question is aimed at advising GCSE students. It is difficult to give examples, because it involves listing so much data, but here are a few:
Histogram example - Height (cm) 5 - 9, 10 - 14, 15 - 19. class widths are each 5 because 5 - 9 interval extends from 4.5 to 9.5. Histogram plotted at 5 - 10, 10 to 15 i.e. lower limit of next class.
Cumulative frequency example - Waiting times (mns) 1 - 3, 4 - 6, 7 - 9. Quote "CF must always be plotted at upper class boundaries i.e. 3.5, 6.5 etc.
Another text uses examples with Weights 500 - 550, 551 - 600, 601 - 650 says that points should be plotted using the upper limit of the range e.g. at 600 for the 550 - 600 (sic) class. it goes on to say, "Examiners ALWAYS check you've got this right! A common mistake is to plot the point between the upper and lower limits. This is an evil, bad, naughty and despicable thing to do". So I really am at a loss as to the correct way to calculate class widths and mid-interval values, and what to use on the "x -axis" when plotting histograms and cumulative frequency curves, and would appreciate any clear advice that applies to any situation.

Comment: No and Yes. Much of the advice on treating grouped data depends on the author and type of data. Before I try to give any particulars, please give information about the mathematical level of the texts to which you refer and your purpose for making a cumulative frequency graph or in 'smoothing' a histogram. In some relevant situations, are you able to retrieve the original data?

Answer (score 0):

Generally I'd expand the data groups to be continuous – for your example $$-0.5\le x<4.5,4.5\le x<9.5$$
This makes the point to plot be $(4,4.5)$ and $(7,9.5)$. However, when dealing with integers (as your example does) I would recommend changing it to $$0\le x<5,5\le x<10$$ instead
and plot the points from there. I hope this was useful.

In short, expand data to be continuous. For floats $(x-1).5\le y<z.5$, for integers $x\le y<z+1$.